# リモートリポジトリへのpush後にメール通知される宛先の設定場所はどこ？

Tags: linux, centos, gitlab

### 気になっていること

ローカルリポジトリからリモートリポジトリへpushする際、そのリポジトリに参加している全員ではなく、特定のユーザにだけメールが送られている。
全員の通知レベルは同じであるため、なぜメールが送られるユーザと送られないユーザが生まれるのかがわからない。
メール対象者を指定するファイルやGUI上の項目などご存知であれば、ご教授の程よろしくお願い致します。

### 実行環境:

GitLab 12.7.0
CentOS 7.6.1810 (Core)

### push時の/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log

以下の[Sent mail to]に指定されている宛先にメール通知(push情報)が行われていた。

```bash
Started POST "/api/v4/internal/allowed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-12-20 19:26:46 +0900
Started POST "/api/v4/internal/allowed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-12-20 19:26:46 +0900
Started POST "/api/v4/internal/pre_receive" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-12-20 19:26:46 +0900
Started POST "/api/v4/internal/post_receive" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-12-20 19:26:46 +0900
Sent mail to hoge@example.com (36.2ms)
Sent mail to hogehuge@example.com (41.0ms)
Sent mail to hogehoge@example.com (22.0ms)
Sent mail to hugeuge@example.com (49.7ms)
Processing by MetricsController#index as HTML
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 自己解決

以下URLの「Recipients」に記載されているアドレスにpush後の通知がきます。
`https://localhost/groupName/projectName/-/services/emails_on_push/edit`